# How to display an infinite blinking / flashing text in Python's shell while waiting for user input?

Tags: python, user-input, infinite-loop

I'm making a text-based game as an exercise and I wanted to tell the user that when an infinite flashing text appears they can input something.

```
from time import sleep

    print("When this signs happear: ")
    user_answer() 

    sleep(2.3)
    print("it means you can input something.")
    user_input = input()

def user_answer():
    while 1:
        print("\r< ", end=""), sleep(1.1)
        print("\r> ", end=""), sleep(1.1)
        continue
```

I tried using `break` instead of `continue` but the problem remains:
when the flashing text is shown, it *is* infinite but the code stops progressing, meaning the line

```
print("it means you can input something.")
```

doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def user_answer():
    while 1:
        print("\r< ", end=""), sleep(1.1)
        print("\r> ", end=""), sleep(1.1)
        continue
```

Since you use an infinite loop, your code is gonna get stuck in the infinite loop.
If I understand correctly you want the loop to be infinite until the user inputs something

To do so, you want to launch your "infinite loop function" inside what is called a thread.

The thread is gonna launch your function, while the main thread (your application) will continue.

Once the user did input, you want to ask the thread printing to stop

Example :

```
from time import sleep
import threading

def user_answer(stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        print("\r< ", end=""), sleep(1.1)
        print("\r> ", end=""), sleep(1.1)

print("When this signs appear: ")

stop_event = threading.Event() # to tell when the thread stops
th = threading.Thread(target=user_answer, args=(stop_event,))
th.start()

print("it means you can input something.")
user_input = input()
if user_input:
    stop_event.set()
    th.join()  # Wait for the thread to stop

# continue your code
```

Comment: you SAVED me, thanks seriously a lot. My first problem was actually that, my while loop simply didn't allow the code to continue; it just stopped in that "animation" of the signs <> infinitely, and didn't continue to print other text. BUT now he manages to print text, even though my initial objective was to make this "infinite 'animation' " function that ALWAYS moves even tho the game goes on, you still solved a great problem of mine, now the code goes in order til the end, thanks again!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, if you want the animation to continue, just remove the lines starting at if(user_input). Also consider marking my response as an answer if it solved your problem. Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

Another solution could be to remove the while loop and put in the for loop
ex:

```
import termcolor
import time, os
os.system("cls") #clearing

a=["white"]
for b in a:
         termcolor.cprint(""*5 "\t\" + "[your flashy text]", b) 
         time.sleep(1)
         os.system("cls") #will clear the above after sleep 
#continue your code
```

Comment: This is buggy (doesn't fix the OP's original problem of the loop not collecting input, or that of the loop not returning that input once the user is done typing; has incorrect escaping), nonportable (`cls` only works on Windows), and inefficient (`os.system()` starts a shell; so you're starting _two_ separate programs, both the shell and a copy of `cls`, every single time you want to clear the screen)